# How can I insert element into beginning of vector?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, std

I need to insert values into the beginning of a `std::vector` and I need other values in this vector to be pushed to further positions for example: something added to beginning of a vector and values moved from position 1 to 2, from 2 to 3 etc.

How can I do that?

Comment: Keep in mind that pushing stuff to the front of the vector is an O(n) operation, so if you need to do it repeatedly you probably want to use a data structure better optimized for that (such as `std::deque`), or use other tricks (e.g. if you only add and remove stuff at the front, just do that at the end and display it in reverse).

Answer (score 133):

Use the [std::vector::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) function accepting an [iterator to the first element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) as a target position (iterator before which to insert the element):

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    v.insert(v.begin(), 6);
}
```

Alternatively, [append](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) the element and perform the [rotation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) to the right:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    v.push_back(6);
    std::rotate(v.rbegin(), v.rbegin() + 1, v.rend());
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call the first parameter of `insert` a hint, I'd say it's more like a target position.

Comment: It is working, thanks a lot. And i have another question. I made loop that compares 2 vectors and when values doesn't match, code is inserting the wrong value to the beginning of the vector. How do i now delete the wrong value from the old position?

Comment: @PawełSzymkowicz: Use `std::rotate` to get it to the first position. Cleaner and more efficient than inserting and deleting.

Comment: @JerryCoffin you mean rotate and then resize to remove the last element? That makes me wonder if there is any use of `push_back` & `rotate` to effectively `push_front`...

Comment: He was asking about getting the equivalent of push_front, so yes, what I meant was a push_back followed by a rotate.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Why `push_back`&`rotate` is faster than `insert`?

Comment: @Hope: note the comment about doing inserting and deleting. If we only needed to insert a value, then yes insert would be the obvious choice. But at least as I read it, we're deleting one, and inserting another (in a different place, so we can't just overwrite the existing value). It's not 100% certain that push_back/rotate will be faster though--he's kind of vague about some details. OTOH, given that we're apparently primarily adding to the front in one case, it's probably also worth considering using a `deque`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Alright, but if we are using a vector, the argument is that the rotate is faster because it is not an O(n) operation like insert, right?

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler be sophisticated enough to do this optimization automatically?

Answer (score 40):

You should consider using `std::deque`. It works a lot like a `std::vector` but you can add and remove items from both the front and the end.

It does this by dividing the internal storage up into smaller blocks. You still have random-access iterators with good lookup speed.

If your container is small it should be fine to use the `std::vector` approach but if you are storing large amounts of data the `std::deque`s performance for inserting/deleting at the front will be far superior.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, rather talks about optimization assuming the author doesn't know about it.

Comment: @AshutoshTiwari It offers a different solution then the accepted answer. That is one of the benefits of having multiple answers for a question. They complement each other.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{ 
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 4, 5, 6 };

    // merge
    std::vector<int> dst;
    std::merge(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(dst));
}
```

Finally dst is: **{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}**

*Note: It is a sample, so you should check if v1 is empty etc.*

Answer (score -1):

You can insert values to `std::vector` from back and then use [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse):

**Example:**

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorhitm>
#include <iostream>

void printVector( std::vector< int > const & _vector )
{
    for( auto value : _vector )
    {
         std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< int > someVec;
    
    someVec.push_back( 5 );
    someVec.push_back( 4 );
    someVec.push_back( 3 );
    someVec.push_back( 2 );
    someVec.push_back( 1 );

    // (1)
    printVector( someVec );

    std::reverse( someVec.begin(), someVec.end() );
    
    // (2)
    printVector( someVec );

    return 0;
}
```

**Output (1):**

```
5 4 3 2 1
```

**Output (2):**

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: If `printVector` took a pair of iterators as arguments rather than a vector reference, reversing the vector wouldn't even be necessary to print it in reverse.

Answer (score -3):

You may try this

```
    vector<int> v={1,2,3,4,5};
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        v.insert(v.begin(),i+1);
    }
```

Output is **{5,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5}**

Every element is shifted to the right after insertion